# signals and slots with a condition

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a mainwindow.ui with a QLineEdit_1 and secondWindow.ui with multiple QLineEdit widgets , in short, i wanted to make a condition where when entering a certain number in QLineEdit_1 would result in text output on some of the QLineEdit widgets as "null" and the rest would still be blank.

what are the main steps to achieving the above 
if also anyone would lead me to an example similar that would be great 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are searching for signal-slot-connections: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html.

In your case listen to `textChanged()` of QLineEdit_1 and create a slot in e.g. secondWindow.ui-class where you set the other line edits as you like:

```
connect(QLineEdit_1, &QLineEdit::textChanged, 
        PointerToSecondWindow, &secondWindow::yourSlot);

// In secondWindow.cpp
void secondWindow::yourSlot(const QString &text) {
    // Do with text whatever you like and set the
    // other line edits.
}
```

Comment: please bear with me am sorry if i piss anyone off with my ignorance am trying to learn .......so i should put the connect line in mainwindow.cpp correct? and use the the pointer to second window as" secondWindow *secondwindow" for example which it should be in the public section in mainwindow.h correct?

Comment: @zakachoka In principle yes. You can put the connect statement wherever you like as long as you have a pointer to a) the line edit in question that emits the signal and b) the pointer to the object that holds the slot. If the pointer to the slot-object is public or private does not matter. You are welcome and go on learning and asking questions. Cheers.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, i have a problem with my if statment as i cant put all of the QLineEdit from both windows in one statement?